# In polymer dart, what are the ways to communicate from parent to child component?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In order to communicate from child to parent, events seem to be the most elegant way.
What are the options to communicate from parent to child?

More specifically, I want a method called in a child when it becomes visible.
These are the ideas I came up with:

- xtag - elegant and works
- observing 'hidden' - didn't manage to get this working, hidden is not marked as observable in Element
- publishing a trigger variable in child, binding and changing it in parent - ugly

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it yet but maybe [MutationObserver](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/be/latest/dart_html/MutationObserver.html) does what you want.

Seth Ladd's polymer examples containes two examples:
The first listens to the onMutation event
https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/blob/master/web/onmutation-mutation-observer/my_element.dart

```dart
library my_element;

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

@CustomTag('my-element')
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  MyElement.created() : super.created() {

    // NOTE this only fires once,
    // see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/llfRAC_cMIo
    // This is useful for waiting for a node to change in response
    // to some data change. Since we don't know when the node will
    // change, we can use onMutation.
    onMutation($['list']).then((List<MutationRecord> records) {
      $['out'].text = 'Change detected at ${new DateTime.now()}';
    });

    new Timer(const Duration(seconds:1), () {
      $['list'].children.add(new LIElement()..text='hello from timer');
    });
  }
}
```

the second example uses the MutationObserver class
https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/blob/master/web/mutation_observers/my_element.dart

=== edit ===

Have you tried the linked example?
The observe method allows to specify what should be observed:

```dart
  /**
   * Observes the target for the specified changes.
   *
   * Some requirements for the optional parameters:
   *
   * * Either childList, attributes or characterData must be true.
   * * If attributeOldValue is true then attributes must also be true.
   * * If attributeFilter is specified then attributes must be true.
   * * If characterDataOldValue is true then characterData must be true.
   */
  void observe(Node target,
               {bool childList,
                bool attributes,
                bool characterData,
                bool subtree,
                bool attributeOldValue,
                bool characterDataOldValue,
                List<String> attributeFilter}) {
```

Comment: I tried that, but with toggling $['list'].hidden on and off. The observer launched only one time - seems like it only notices elemets added and removed to the dom

Comment: This is by design. MutationObserver fires only once and than you have to subscribe again.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate from parent polymer to child polymer , this solution works good for me.

If we have a child polymer element like this:

```js
library my_element;

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

@CustomTag('my-element')
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  MyElement.created() : super.created() {
  }

  myCustomMethod(param){
    print("pass-in param = $param");
  }

}
```

To access to your child element from parent:

1. Query your child polymer element in parent element (yes, access to the HTML element first)
2. Cast it to the binding Class (ex: MyElement.dart in our case)

```html
  (theParentClass.querySelector("my-element") as MyElement).myCustomMethod({"done":true});
```